# How to set in android background color to several linearlayouts at time in for() loop?

Tags: android, loops

Android. I am trying to set background colour at time to make some sort of trainer. But this loop set  background colour for all 4 LivearLayouts at ONE TIME - after the last iteration. And i need to do it one by one with pauses. How can i do it?

```
    private LinearLayout[] lls;
    lls = new LinearLayout[4];
    lls[0] = findViewById(R.id.ll01);
    lls[1] = findViewById(R.id.ll02);
    lls[2] = findViewById(R.id.ll03);
    lls[3] = findViewById(R.id.ll04);
    public void onClick(View view) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            lls[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("red"));
        }
    }
```

Such a code changes colour for all 4 objects at once - after the end of the 4th iteration. Prior to this, the colour of none has changed.

Comment: You use RxJava in your project ?

Comment: No, only Java in Android Studio https://youtu.be/YxQwNoBInz8

Comment: So your desired output is - 4 items changing color one after another (so it should take 12 seconds). Right ?

Comment: give me 5 minutes I'll give you with sample code.

Comment: Dmitrii Leonov - yes (4 items changing color one after another). And more - i want to have ability to change the time of such pauses!

Comment: I had added my answer, as you said you can change your pause time also.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a handler instead of for loop. Handlers are more convenient for delaying and doing some stuff. I am putting some edited code for you.

```
private LinearLayout[] lls;

private Long timeInMillis = 3000L;

private Handler handler;

private Runnable runnable;

private int index = 0;

private void setColors(){
    lls = new LinearLayout[4];
    lls[0] = findViewById(R.id.ll01);
    lls[1] = findViewById(R.id.ll02);
    lls[2] = findViewById(R.id.ll03);
    lls[3] = findViewById(R.id.ll04);

    handler = new Handler();

    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(index!=lls.length){
                lls[index++].setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("red"));
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,timeInMillis);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(runnable,timeInMillis);

}
```

Comment: That is, the color does not change when it is indicated in the code, but when does the operating system decide to do it? And insert two pauses even harder?
Set the default color.
Wait 3000 ms.
Change the color to red.
Wait 400 ms.
Change color to default.
For such operations can not do a simple loop? Pity.

Comment: Can you provide a flow of how you need the color-changing? I can give you a better and optimized solution for that.

Comment: How do i make in Android smth like THIS http://maxbarannyk.ru/tests/trainer/index.html ??

Comment: Code above worked one time. Maybe i make a mistake when used it.

Comment: Requirements I understood, Please share the whole code so I  can provide you a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

It was wrong code. You cant change smth in activity  in one thread. It was solved by adding thread with loop that sends Broadcast messages for BroadcastReciever in MainActivity.

Comment: Hi Max. Thanks for the explanation. Can you please provide the code as well? Kind Regards.